# How to implement dependency injection in .net core 2.2 console application

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I am creating a small console application using .net core 2.2 and i am trying to implement dependency injection with my app. 
I am getting some unhandled exceptions.

**Person.cs**

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

**IPersonRepository**

```
public interface IPersonRepository
{
     bool AddPerson(Person entity);
     IEnumerable<Person> GetAllPersons();
}
```

**PersonRepository.cs**

```
 public class PersonRepository:IPersonRepository
 {
        private readonly IPersonRepository _personRepository;

        public PersonRepository(IPersonRepository personRepository)
        {
            _personRepository = personRepository;
        }

        public bool AddPerson(Person entity)
        {
            _personRepository.AddPerson(entity);
            return true;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Person> GetAllPersons()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
  }
```

**Program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace ConsoleAppWithDI
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddTransient<IPersonRepository, PersonRepository>()
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            var personRepositoryObj = serviceProvider
                .GetService<IPersonRepository>();

            personRepositoryObj
                .AddPerson(new Person
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Name = "Tom",
                    Age = 24,
                    Gender = "Male"
                });
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this [Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIqXh.png). Can anybody tell me where i am making mistake ? Also i would like to know when making .exe in console app (which does not runs 24*7) using DI is safe ?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your person Repository takes in a IPersonRepository, The Dependency Injector is trying to create a class in which it needs to inject itself. You probably want to take in a DbContext instead.  This code assumes you've created a DbContext Named `ApplicationContext`

```
private readonly ApplicationContext _context;

public PersonRepository(ApplicationContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

public bool AddPerson(Person entity)
{
    _context.Persons.Add(entity);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public PersonRepository(IPersonRepository personRepository)
{
    _personRepository = personRepository;
}
```

This is your problem. You need to remove the IPersonRepository parameter from the constructor because its trying to create an instance of itself within itself. Hence, your circular reference issue